# Efficiently querying a B+ Tree holding multidimensional data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, multidimensional-array, b-tree

I have a collection of tuples `(x,y)` of 64-bit integers that make up my dataset. I have, say, trillions of these tuples; it is not feasible to keep the dataset in memory on any machine on earth. However, it is quite reasonable to store them on disk.

I have an on-disk store (a B+-tree) that allow for the quick, and concurrent, querying of data in a single dimension. However, some of my queries rely on both dimensions.

Query examples:

- Find the tuple whose `x` is greater than or equal than some given value
- Find the tuple whose `x` is as small as possible s.t. it's `y` is greater than or equal to some given value
- Find the tuple whose `x` is as small as possible s.t. it's `y` is less than or equal to some given value
- Perform maintenance operations (insert some tuple, remove some tuple)

The best bet I have found are Z-order curves but I cannot seem to figure out how to conduct the queries given my two dimensional data-set.

Solutions that are not acceptable include a sequential scan of the data, this could be far too slow.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the most appropriate data structures for your requirements are [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and its variants (R*-tree, R+-tree, Hilbert R-tree). R-tree is similar to B+-tree, but also allows multidimensional queries.

Other relevant data structure is Priority Search Tree. It is good for queries like your examples 1 .. 3, but not very efficient if you need frequent updates or on-disk store. For details see [this paper](http://wwwisg.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/ag/lehre/SS2009/GDS/slides/S10.pdf) or this book: ["Handbook of Data Structures and Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584884355) (Chapter 18.5).

Comment: I cannot afford a robust implementation of R-trees (of any variant), the additional work to make it crash safe and transactional is beyond the ambition of the project.

Comment: @user1290696: You can throw it into a RDBMS that supports R-trees (or variants), like Postgres or SQL-Server.

Comment: I cannot do that, it is an embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you don't know how to query z-order curves?  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) describes how you do range searches.

A z-curve divides your space into nested rectangles, where each additional bit in the key divides the space in half.  To search for a point:

```
Start with the largest rectangle that might contain your point.

    Recursively:

        Create a result set of rectangles    

    For each rectangle in your set        
        If the rectangle is a single point, you are done, it is what you are looking for.
        Otherwise, divide the rectangle in two (specify one additional bit of the z-curve)
            If both halves contain a point
                If one half is better 
                    Add that rectangle to your result set of rectangles
                Otherwise
                    Add both rectangles to your result set of rectangles
            Otherwise, only one half contains a point
                    Add that rectangle to your result set of rectangles

    Search your result set of rectangles
```

Worst case performance is bad, of course.  You can adjust it by changing how you construct your z-order index.

Comment: I think those were just query examples, not the full range of queries they might need. That said, for two variables, I guess that's at most 4 different indexes (i.e., x, y, x+y and x-y), so, sure. :)

Comment: This does not work, take example 2: I am looking for a `y` of at least 20 with the smallest `x` possible. Concatenating `y` and `x` and creating greater-than-or-equal-to query for `y+x` would look like `20+0`. This could find `20+50` but would skip over `21+10`.

Comment: My bad-- I didn't understand the needs of your queries, which are truly 2d.  I'll try another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on designing a data structure which is essentially a 'stacked' B+ tree (or a *d*+ tree where *d* is the number of dimensions) for multidimensional data. I believe it would suit your data perfectly and is being designed specifically for your use case.

The basic idea is this:

Each dimension is a B+ tree and is linked to the next dimension's B+ tree. Search through the first dimension normally, once a leaf is reached it contains a pointer to the root of the next B+ tree which belongs to the next dimension. Everything in the second B+ tree belongs to the same `x` value.

The original plan was to only store the unique values for each dimension along with it's count. This employs a very simple compression algorithm (if you can even call it that) while still allowing for the entire data set to be represented. This 'linked' dimension scheme could allow for extra dimensions to be added later as they are simply added to the stack of B+ trees.

Total insert/search/delete time for 2 dimensions would be something similar to this:

```
log b(card(x)) + log b(card(y))
```

where *b* is the base of each B+ tree and *card(x)* would be the cardinality of the *x* dimension.

I hope that makes sense. I'm still working on an implementation, however feel free to use or even augment the idea.

Answer (score 0):

http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

> Tokyo Cabinet is a library of routines for managing a database. The database is a simple data file containing records, each is a pair of a key and a value. Every key and value is serial bytes with variable length. Both binary data and character string can be used as a key and a value. There is neither concept of data tables nor data types. Records are organized in hash table, B+ tree, or fixed-length array.
>
> Tokyo Cabinet is written in the C language, and provided as API of C, Perl, Ruby, Java, and Lua. Tokyo Cabinet is available on platforms which have API conforming to C99 and POSIX. Tokyo Cabinet is a free software licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License.

may it easy for u to embed?